# How to parse DNS response sent by the server?

Tags: python, sockets, parsing, dns

I have successfully made a DNS request and I send it to my DNS server using UDP sockets in python. Then, I receive the response and convert into a byte-array using python's `bytearray()` method. But this response contains many jibberish, non-important data in addition to the IP addresses of the canonical server. How should I parse this response to get a result like this :

[image]

I am getting the values of the IP address like `74.125.200.106` and all in the response, but how should I extract it from the response bytearray?

Comment: You should probably use code one would imagine; unfortunately we can't help you adjust it though without seeing it.

Comment: I have made a simple DNS query by hard coding flags, arcount, nscount and other values, sent this message using UDP socket and am now receiving some content from server. This contains the IP addresses as well as other things as well. I just need to know how to parse DNS response sent by the DNS server. I can't find any pattern in it to extract the IP addresses. @l'L'l

Comment: Are we supposed to know what the jibberish looks like though? Parse it with code! That's the answer...

Comment: Please see the response here : https://pastebin.com/2eTLf7H2 If you perform `nslookup` on `www.google.com`, you see there are IP's starting from `74.` and the same can be found at multiple places in the given response. I need to know how to extract these strings starting with `74.` @l'L'l

Comment: Hmmm the problem with that is there doesn't seem to be a definitive pattern that is consistent enough for you to accurately pull out the numbers associated with the ip address from what it looks like.

Comment: Exactly ! If I use `www.facebook.com`, it becomes totally different. I can't find a particular offset from where I should extract the IP addresses. @l'L'l

Comment: Yeah maybe post another example also, I do see a pattern after the first port 80 is shown, but like you said it could be 8080 on the next one. It could help to compare I suppose. What are you using to get that output?

Comment: Here is an example for `www.facebook.com` : https://pastebin.com/0yx4PYfA The IP address starts with `157.` and is the only IP address in the `nslookup` output. @l'L'l

Comment: I am getting that output directly from this code : `response = bytearray(socket.recv(512))` @l'L'l I convert it to bytearray to make it readable.

Comment: That's never going to work only using a `bytearray`; generally you would pack and unpack it to then have it output in a meaningful way. There are some helpful examples here: https://joshmcculloch.nz/#!python-network-udp-intro. In particular look at the one titled "Broadcast - Discover peers on your LAN", the ip should output nicely using that method.

Comment: I can't seem to know what to do with the received response. @l'L'l The given example is not parsing the received output in any way.

Comment: As mentioned before there's no telling what you're doing with your code so beyond that there's really not much more I can help you with. I suggest running the example and learning from it, as it deals with the packets and outputs the ip just fine for me.

Comment: Please see the code here: http://ideone.com/nS6Kx6, for some reasons, I can't post it here. @li

Comment: In the last line, please replace it (`192.168.35.52`) with your DNS server. @l'L'l

Comment: Either use some DNS parsing library (like [dnslib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dnslib) or [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/)) or read the [DNS standard](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) to understand on how the wire format works and parse it accordingly.

Comment: Apparently, some "people" _did_ see my _code in the comments_ (thanks to ideone !!). This was an assignment and that's why I didn't post the code in the question. Anyways, the [**complete**](https://github.com/saurabh3896/Networks) code is posted on Github now. Don't forget to STAR the repo !!!